# Is there any country in the OECD where mob justice is prevalent?

Tags: oecd, social-justice

In some parts of the world, there is something called "mob justice." I.e., they take law into their own hands to punish criminals. This is because people think their judicial system is not protecting their rights. This could be either because of corruption or the combined inefficiency of the police and judiciary.

E.g., in India, rapists and/or small-time criminals are frequently lynched to death.

Is there any country in the OECD where mob justice is prevalent?

Comment: Too vague. What does "prevalent" mean? It might be possible to find figures for deaths by lynching but I've no idea how many you'd need for it to be prevalent. And that excludes other less severe forms of crowd justice, e.g. public shaming or tutting.

Comment: And while in India people can probably be lynched, one could equally remark the same about Pakistan.  Neither India nor Pakistan being in the OECD so not sure why either needs citing.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, *one could equally remark the same about Pakistan.* --- Give me at least one example.

Comment: I am voting to close as a push question as the OP appears to be looking for a yes answer and criticizing an answer that says no with single examples of someone taking justice in their hands and trying to suggest that it represent the countries as a whole.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynching_of_Priyantha_Kumara https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/2/13/man-lynched-by-mob-over-blasphemy-allegation-in-pakistan-police https://tribune.com.pk/story/2363510/police-rescue-paedophile-from-lynching-mob  More generally searching "Pakistan lynching mob" gives lots of hits.  Pretty much like doing the same for India.  Remove the bit singling out idea, change it to "poor countries" or the like and we can all stop slinging mud that isn't warranted by the question.

Answer (score 4):

No.

All the countries in the OECD have functioning governments and justice systems (this is one of the expectations of members). There are a few cases of "vigilante justice", and in many countries there are communities that may distrust the police and judicial system, but in none of the OECD countries could this be described as "prevalent", or the normal way of punishing criminals.